# How to add different links to two images in header

Tags: html

I have added 2 images to my header and all looks fine, but I want each image to have a different link when I try adding href to the second image both images inherit this link. What am I missing. I am new to html.. Thanks

```html
<div class="main-header-container container-fluid">
<div class="container">

<!--<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="mainmenu" role="navigation">-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="mainmenu">

 <div class="nav-container">
    
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
 
        <a class="navbar-brandf" href="<?php echo site_url().'/link1.html'; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.svg" alt="Logo1" class="img-responsive" />
     </a></div>

 <a class="navbar-brandf" href="<?php echo site_url().'/link2.html'; ?>">
        <div class="navbar-world">
            <img src="/images/tag.png" alt="Logo2" style="width:90px; height:80px" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: show more of the code please, this snippet is meaningless on its own. Show how you've built both links together. It looks like maybe you've made a syntax error or something, but it's unclear from this.

Comment: Kindly share [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code.

Comment: Using the snippets feature can be useful … but you need to populate it with HTML … not PHP.

Comment: as well as the PHP, please show what the finished output looks like in your browser's "View Source" function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add two different images, with two different `href`s/ links:

```
<a href="**link1**"><img src"**path_to_image_1**" /></a>
<a href="**link2**"><img src"**path_to_image_2**" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has PHP errors and some missing tags. Try the following snippet to fit your requirements, make the required changes in 'href' value based on your target link (href="")

```
<div class="navbar-header">

    <a class="navbar-brandf" href="<?php echo site_url().'/link1.html'; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo.svg'; ?>" alt="Logo" class="img-responsive" />
    </a>

    <a class="navbar-brandf" href="<?php echo site_url().'/link2.html'; ?>">
        <div class="navbar-world">
            <img src="QS-tag.png" alt="Logo" style="width:90px; height:80px" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
    </a>

</div><!--navbar-header-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try that the same thing happens. Both images link to link2.html (as above). I will add the full code, maybe that will help. Thanks.

Comment: Added full code top. In isolation your code works, but when I add the code to my page both images inherit link-2.html. If I delete the class/code for link-2.html, link-1.html works. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: If it's the complete code you have posted, it's still missing some closing `</div> </nav>` tags. The link should have worked otherwise, as it seems working in the output of your code snippet also.